# how to change OutPut Pin Size & ColorSpace/Compression in DirectShow

Tags: directshow

how to change OutPut Pin Size & ColorSpace/Compression of a Video Source Filter in DirectShow

I want to Know whre the Output Pin PropertyPage Datas are stored and how can I Change those Datas By My Code

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write your own transformation filter.  Or you can use a filter like [FFDShow](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/) that supports image resizing among other video modifications and enhancements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IPin::EnumMediaTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390426%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on your filter's output pin to get a list of supported media types / video formats.

Afterwards, call [IAMStreamConfig::GetFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319785%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get the current format in an AM_MEDIA_TYPE structure. Modify this structure as you wish (make sure your format is supported by the device), and call [IAMStreamConfig::SetFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319788%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) with the same structure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But for a beginner in Direct Show it is not really helpfull. Can you please tell me where I get the IPin and IAMStreamConfig interfaces from ? In my code I have a IGraphBuilder, ICaptureGraphBuilder2, IBaseFilter, IVMRWindowlessControl9, IMediaControl, but no IPin. A peace of code would be VERY helpfull!