# Changing resolution and filters in DirectShow

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windows-8, camera, directshow

I’m making a Windows form application for a Windows 8 tablet in VB.NET 2010 using DirectShow (which is quite new to me). In my code I take the video feed from the inbuilt 8Mp Camera/Webcam and I save the picture.

Currently the saved picture is 640x480 pixels and has jagged edges.

Can anyone help me to improve the quality? I´m looking for general techniques to capture a 1024x768 pixels picture which is smooth.

Most forum posts have to do with playing video files, so any help is welcome.

I’m looking forward to your reply

Comment: see also [how to change OutPut Pin Size & ColorSpace/Compression in DirectShow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/708862/33499) and [Can't make IAMStreamConfig.SetFormat() to work with LifeCam Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7383372/33499)